# Woocommerce - Showing a different page on click for a specific category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, product

I need to set a different page for a specific woocommerce category. I have created that page in admin panel. When any user will click on that category then I need to open a different page.

All other categories will show products on click. I need to set different pages for some specific categories. I know that we can create a template with taxonomy name but I do not need to create it as a template. I need to call admin page.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly that you wish redirect a product category to a WordPress *page*, then you can use the `template_redirect` hook.

```
function so_38101215_template_redirect(){
    if( function_exists( 'is_product_category' ) && is_product_category( 'redirect_this_category' ) ){
        $redirect_page_id = 99; // adjust to ID of page you are redirecting to
        wp_redirect( get_permalink( $redirect_page_id ) );
        exit();
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'so_38101215_template_redirect' );
```

`template_redirect` is fired after the query is fully set up, so you'll be able to use standard conditional logic to determine when you want to run your redirection.

Answer (score 1):

Use `taxonomy-$taxonomy.php` as your template, where `$taxonomy` is `product_cat`. If for a particular category you need different structure then use `taxonomy-$taxonomy-$term.php`. `$term` is your specific product category.

And make sure you copy WooCommerce category template content to be copied here and then make your changes as you need.

By the way what do you mean by 'i need to call admin page' ? from these templates you need some admin access ?